# Local version of a Wordpress site - SSL/HTTPS enforced?

Tags: ssl, https, localhost

I am trying to setup a local version of a website that is live, I have downloaded the files and database and believe it is all ready and sorted, but I am having an issue whereby the site is trying to force HTTPS and so all browsers are reporting 'This site can’t provide a secure connection,
localhost sent an invalid response.'.

What is the way to handle this? Am I supposed to try to install a certificate?

I am running MAMP for the apache and mysql servers.

Answer (score 8):

WordPress keeps `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` in DB, this is set during initial installation and usually is the domain of your website, in your case it is a domain with `https`.

Your visiting site via local domain, but WordPress redirects to https live domain, causing redirect loop which obviously fails.

To fix this, change `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` values in DB.

Or simply add this to wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://domain.local');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://domain.local');
```

Also remember that your browser is caching redirects aggressively. You need to clean cache to see results, or use browser incognito mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's not working unfortunately though.

I set the changes on both the database and the wp-config file and made sure to use incognito mode.

Comment: @Josh try to clear the cache then.

Answer (score 0):

you can also check if there are any plugins you have installed to support SSL. If so remove the plugin manually from the plugins folder.